# setting parent class attribute using type

Tags: python

What is the reason why this code doesn't work?

```
class Parent:
  l = []

  def __init__(self, val):
    print("l is: " + str(Parent.l))

C = type('Child', (Parent,), {})
C.l = [1, 2]

C(1) # prints "l is []" rather than "l is [1,2]"
```

Comment: Do you just have a typo where you meant `print("l is: " + str(self.l))` or are you searching for an explanation as to why printing `self.l` and `Parent.l` is different?

Comment: @KentShikama It's not a typo. I'd like to programmatically set my parent's class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, written more traditionally, is:

```
class Parent:
    l = []

    def __init__(self, val):
        print("l is: " + str(Parent.l))

class C(Parent):
    l = [1, 2]

C(1)
```

When calling `C(1)`, `__init__` of `Parent` is called, because `Child` doesn't overload it, and it explicitely prints `Parent.l`, so `[]`.

If you want to use the `l` defined in your current class, you could access it through the instance:

```
class Parent:
    l = []

    def __init__(self, val):
        print("l is:", self.l)

C = type('Child', (Parent,), {})
C.l = [1, 2]

C(1)
# l is: [1, 2]
```